# Library for solving knapsack-prblm(integer-programming)

Tags: knapsack-problem, integer-programming

I am trying to solve the knapsack-problem, which is also an integer-programming problem. I have looked at several approximate solutions like dynamic-programming, greedy algorithm, branch-and-bound algorithm, genetic algorithms. Can you tell me a library(in any language) that helps implementing any/all of these algorithms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The JBoss Drools library - http://www.jboss.org/drools/ - has knapsack algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few implementations of the Knapsack Problem (KP):

- **CPLEX** If you are familiar with CPLEX (IBM) they have a page for Knapsack (among many other IP formulations) [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/odmeinfo/v3r4/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.ide.odme.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/ODME/_pubskel/ODME_pubskels/startall_ODME34_Eclipse1778.html).
- **Java:** They also have a Java implementaion of the knapsack problem [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplexamples/topics/uss_opl_mp_examples_2.html). (look specifically at `javaknapsack.mod`)
- **Python**: Here's [one example](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/python/knapsack.py) of multiple solution techniques of the Knapsack problem.(by Dave Eppstein)
- **CPP**: Here's [a Genetic Algorithm implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607791/ga-knapsack) of the KP.

A simple web-search should get you many more examples because the knapsack problem is easy to solve (and to teach) using several of the techniques you mention.